# Как из 1 select сделать 2 иерархичных на jquery?

Tags: jquery, select

Пожалуйста, не бейте ногами, может поставленная задача уже решена, но я никак не могу найти.

Хотя подобное что-то проскакивало jquery-select-hierarchy-master, но не то.

Суть такова, есть select с марками и моделями автомобилей, например. Но в одном селекте сморится очень громоздко.

Можно ли как-то на jquery развить его на 2 иерархических селекта как вот тут autostan.kz?
то есть выбираем BMW и во втором селекте появляются модели - 320, 520, 630 и так далее

Comment: Плохо искали - [Связанные списки select jQuery](http://bit.ly/X85RBh)

Comment: спасибо lampa, хороший вариант так как пока что плохо разбираюсь в аяксе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Схем придумать можно много. Общая примерно такая:

На изменение главного селекта([change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)) Вы вешаете обработчик, который будет запрашивать сервер ([ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) на данные для второго селекта и, при получени данных, Вы просто обновляете ими второй селект.

Answer (score 1):

я делал так: [JavaScript динамические списки](http://lampacore.ru/2012/05/06/javascript-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8/)